# Assembly - Carry flag VS overflow flag

Tags: assembly, x86, carryflag, eflags, signed-overflow

I have the next code:

```
mov al, -5
add al, 132
add al, 1
```

As I check it, the overflow flag and the carry flag will set in the first operation, and in the second, only the overflow will set.

But I don't understand why:

1. In unsigned number, the result is 143 (8FH), and for that is fit 8-bit unsigned number (is smaller than 255)  => the carry flag shouldn't be set. In signed number, the result is 127, It's fit to 8-bit signed, and the overflow shouldn't be set.

Whats wrong? Thanks.

Comment: See Understanding Carry vs. Overflow conditions/flags, http://teaching.idallen.com/dat2343/10f/notes/040_overflow.txt

Answer (score 20, accepted):

In unsigned arithmetic, you have added `0xFB` to `0x84`, i.e. 251 + 132, which indeed is larger than 8-bit, and so the carry flag is set.

In the second case, you are adding +127 to 1, which indeed exceeds a signed 8-bit range, and so the overflow flag is set.

Comment: So the overflow is set only when I do 'add al, 1'? If I will delete this line, the overflow will not set?

Comment: @Tom: The overflow will be set by both `add` instructions.

Comment: So you can explain me please where the overflow set? because as I understood it, in the range of -128 to 127 is not affecting the overflow.

Comment: @Tom O: Convert all your values to signed 8-bit.  In the first `add`, you're doing -5 + -124, which exceeds -128.  In the second `add`, you're doing +127 + +1, which exceeds +127.

Answer (score 32):

Overflow occurs when the result of adding two positive numbers is negative or
                     the result of adding two negative numbers is positive.
For instance:
`+127+1=?`

```
+127=0111 1111
  +1=0000 0001
     ---------
     1000 0000
```

As we look at the sign bits of the two operands and the sign bit of
                 the result, we find out that Overflow occurred and the answer is incorrect.

Comment: The V flag also turns to 1 when we add two negative and the result is 0. If we `adds r0, r1, r0`, where `r0 = 0x80000000`, `r1 = 0x80000000`, after execution, `Z = 1`, `C = 1`, `V = 1`