How do X86 Register Flags work in Binary Subtraction
I’m trying to understand how X86 register flags behave during binary subtraction. I was reading about flags like OF (Overflow Flag), CF (Carry Flag), etc., and I’ve worked through the following example:
I want to compute 54C2 (Hexadecimal) - 3271 (Hexadecimal), and since subtraction is done using addition, I used the two's complement method:
Represent 54C2 in binary:
54C2 --> 0101 0100 1100 0010
Two's Complement of 3271:
One's Complement of 3271 (0011 0010 0111 0001):
1100 1101 1000 1110
Add 1 to get Two’s Complement:
1100 1101 1000 1111
This is the addition we have now: 54C2 + (-3271):
  0101 0100 1100 0010 --> 54C2
+ 1100 1101 1000 1111 --> -3271
-------------------------
1 0010 0010 0101 0001

Here’s my issue:
When I check the flags in an 8086 Online Emulator, all flags (OF, CF, AF, etc.) are 0. However, based on my understanding:
Overflow Flag (OF): I expect this to be 1 because the result appears to exceed 16 bits (17 bits are present after the addition). Other Flags: I’m unsure why the flags like AForCF are cleared.
How's it possible in this case all flags become Zero?
My Code:
mov reg, 0x54C2
sub reg, 0x3271

I’m confused about how the flags are calculated here and would appreciate clarification.
Thanks in advance.

Start by reading https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8496185/assembly-carry-flag-vs-overflow-flag and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19301498/carry-flag-auxiliary-flag-and-overflow-flag-in-assembly?rq=3.  The one other thing to know is that for a SUB instruction, the sense of CF is reversed; it is set only if adding the two's complement did not produce a carry.  This means it is set precisely when the subtraction "borrowed", i.e. subtracted a larger value from a smaller, when the values are interpreted as unsigned.

Still a duplicate of multiple other Q&As, like I linked on the staging ground version of this.  https://stackoverflow.com/posts/79283740/timeline .  x86's sub CF result is the inverse of the carry-out from adding the negative.  It's a borrow flag.  Same for AF.  As for OF, that's not how you determine if a subtraction has signed overflow.  Or an addition: https://teaching.idallen.com/dat2343/10f/notes/040_overflow.txt

There is no overflow. 0x54c2 = 21698. 0x3271 = 12913. The mathematical result of 21698 - 12913 is 8785, which easily fits in a 16-bit register with no overflow.
